# Classifier model: is it possible to assign a label of -1 to a class?

Tags: python, classification, lightgbm

I'm trying to train a light gradient boosting machine classification algorithm (LGBMClassifier). I have three classes in my data, and I assigned them -1, 0 and 1. These labels hold specific meaning, so I would not like to change them to other labels (like 0, 1 and 2).

When I try to train the model, I get the following error message:

```
Label must be in [0, 3), but found -1 in label
```

It is a requirement that if I have three labels, they have to be designated 0,1 and 2?

Update #1

Thanks JST99, this is the correct approach. I defined it as below and it worked correctly. Take note, when you run predict, the output is a probability vector of length n_classes, and if you convert this to the class with the highest probability using `np.argmax` you will have classes ranging from 0 to n (ie you have to take care to convert this back to your original classes, [-1,0,1] in my case).

```
hyperparameter_dictionary = {'task': 'train',
                            'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
                            'objective': 'multiclass',
                            'metric': 'multi_logloss',
                            'num_leaves': 100,
                            'learning_rate': 0.05,
                            'feature_fraction': 0.9,
                            'bagging_fraction': 0.9,
                            'bagging_freq': 0,
                            'verbose': -1,
                            'num_class': 3,
                            'classes': [-1, 0, 1]
                            }
model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(**hyperparameter_dictionary)
model.fit(X,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html), you can specify an additional `kwarg` argument `classes` when initializing the classifier. Specifically, `classes` is of

> Type: array of shape = [n_classes]

Therefore, we can try something like

```py
clf = lightgbm.LGBMClassifier(..., classes=[-1, 0, 1])
```